# Integrate XML API code in Classic ASP website for a HSBC payment gateway integration

Tags: xml, asp-classic, payment-gateway

I have a website which is having paypal integration (all using classic ASP).

Now we need to remove Paypal and integrate the HSBC gateway using XML API. I need to know how to integrate the XML code in classic ASP from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx) MSDN entry for a beginner's tutorial for working with XML.

Then take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757878(v=vs.85).aspx) MSDN article for API documentation.

Other source on StackOverflow:
[Asp XML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94689/asp-xml-parsing)

Depending on the requirements of HSBC you can then build XML requests and parse XML responses. If HSBC is offering a SOAP service then the following resource might be handy:

[Classic ASP Tutorial: How to do Soap Requests](http://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/classic-asp-soap-request-code-example/)