# asp vbscript httpxml response string manipulation

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a vbscript that runs a soap request and gets a

```
 httpxml.responcetext
```

response. when i dump it in a varable and print it, i get the response string just fine, when i try to

```
mid() or left()
```

it, it starts messing with an xml envalope the response is sitting in. whats the solution.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to navigate/traverse/extract the data? Is the data in XML format? Take a look at this question. Not sure if it pertains to what you're trying to do or not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908526/traversing-all-nodes-in-an-xml-file-with-vbscript

Answer (score 1):

I think that your first mistake it's that you are showing it on a browser (what you get, a direct response.write) and you only see the text, but **THERE'S XML ENVELOPE THERE!!**

look at the source code of the page to see if there's some XML enveloping... 
if so.. you'll have to parse it like XML....

This link may be of some assistance: [Asp XML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94689/asp-xml-parsing)